# Can I create React Native project with android kotlin, not java language?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't init new react-native project with kotlin language for android, only create with java language. Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Android Kotlin project separately using Android Studio and follow this guide(https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps?language=kotlin) to integrate react-native into newly created Android Kotlin project

Answer (score 0):

Creating a project with Kotlin using a `cli command` is not available; however, you can make modifications to the project after its creation by following these steps. A detailed, step-by-step guide on creating a project with Kotlin and Swift in a React Native environment is provided in this [React Native Project with Kotlin and Swift - Medium article](https://anilsisodiya.medium.com/react-native-project-with-kotlin-and-swift-4169083ee847).